# Deploying Django app on AWS Lightsail container, getting 'Invalid HTTP_HOST header' error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, containers

Deploying Django app on AWS Lightsail container, getting 'Invalid HTTP_HOST header' error with '172.26.43.151:8000'. Tried adding '172.26.43.151' to ALLOWED_HOSTS, but the error persists
because AWS Lightsail container does not have static IP.

Tried ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*'], but it didn't work. How can I successfully deploy my Django app on Lightsail container with correct Docker files

this is my files

**Dockerfile
**

```
# Use the official Python base image
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client libpq-dev gcc nginx

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project files
COPY . /code/

# Collect static files
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# Run migrations
RUN python manage.py migrate

# Create superuser if it doesn't exist
RUN echo "from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model; User = get_user_model(); User.objects.filter(username='admin').exists() or User.objects.create_superuser('admin@example.com', 'admin', 'admin')" | python manage.py shell

# Copy Nginx configuration
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start Gunicorn
CMD ["gunicorn", "project.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--workers", "4", "--timeout", "300"]
```

**docker-conpose.yml
**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=False
      - SECRET_KEY=
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=*
      - DATABASE_URL=sslmode=require
      - STATIC_URL=/static/
      - MEDIA_URL=/media/
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**default.conf
**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /code/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /code/media/;
    }
}
```

**.env
**

```
DEBUG=False
SECRET_KEY=ALLOWED_HOSTS=*
DATABASE_URL=sslmode=require
STATIC_URL=/static/
MEDIA_URL=/media/
```

base.py

```
import os
from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path

import environ
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.apps import apps
from django.utils.functional import LazyObject, empty
# Other imports

# from apps.auth_users.models import AccessTokenLifetime
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured


env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

# Take environment variables from .env file
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env"))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env("DEBUG")


ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
# ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_HOSTS", "").split(",")


# Application definition

BASE_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    "apps.users_management.apps.users_managementConfig",
    "apps.auth_users.apps.AuthUsersConfig",
    "apps.dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig",
    "apps.site_settings.apps.SiteSettingsConfig",
    "apps.hotels_management.apps.HotelsManagementConfig",
    # "apps.accounts.apps.AccountsConfig",
    "apps.room_reservations.apps.RoomReservationsConfig",
    "apps.profiles.apps.ProfilesConfig",
    "apps.rooms_management.apps.RoomsManagementConfig",
    "apps.contracts_management.apps.ContractsManagementConfig",
    "apps.inventory_managements.apps.InventoryManagementsConfig",
    "apps.permissions_management.apps.PermissionsManagementConfig",
    "apps.history_management.apps.HistoryManagementConfig",
    "apps.offers.apps.OffersConfig",
    "apps.room_booking.apps.RoomBookingConfig",
]

THIRD_PARTIES = [
    "widget_tweaks",
    "cities_light",
    "rest_framework",
    "phonenumber_field",
    "corsheaders",
    "drf_yasg",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist",
    'ipware',
]

INSTALLED_APPS = BASE_APPS + LOCAL_APPS + THIRD_PARTIES



MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    "project.middleware.IPWhitelistMiddleware",
    "apps.site_settings.middlewares.DefaultLanguageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "apps.site_settings.middlewares.ThemeMiddleware",
]



SIMPLE_JWT = {
    # 'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': get_access_token_lifetime,
    "ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=14),
    "REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=14),
    "ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS": True,
    "BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION": True,
    "UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN": False,
    "ALGORITHM": "HS256",
    "SIGNING_KEY": SECRET_KEY,
    "VERIFYING_KEY": None,
    "AUDIENCE": None,
    "ISSUER": None,
    "JWK_URL": None,
    "LEEWAY": 0,
    "AUTH_HEADER_TYPES": ("Bearer",),
    "AUTH_HEADER_NAME": "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION",
    "USER_ID_FIELD": "id",
    "USER_ID_CLAIM": "user_id",
    "USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE": "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule",
    "AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES": ("rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken",),
    "TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM": "token_type",
    "JTI_CLAIM": "jti",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM": "refresh_exp",
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME": timedelta(minutes=5),
    "SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME": timedelta(days=1),
}
# JWT_CONFIG_ID = 'jwt_config_id'


ROOT_URLCONF = "project.urls"


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
        # other authentication classes
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    # other settings
}


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
            ],
            "libraries": {
                "custom_tags": "apps.room_reservations.templatetags.custom_tags",  # Added here
            },
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "project.wsgi.application"



DATABASES = {"default": env.db_url("DATABASE_URL")}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGES = (
    ("ar", _("Arabic")),
    ("en", _("English")),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),)

# LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
# LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ar'

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = env("STATIC_URL")
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

# Media files
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = env("MEDIA_URL")

# Auth User Model
# AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users_management.User"
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "auth_users.CustomUser"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

# Email Settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"


# Auth URLS
# from django.urls import reverse_lazy
# LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy("auth_users:login")

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

my directory structure

```
project_folder/
├─ Dockerfile
├─ docker-compose.yml
├─ requirements.txt
├─ .env
├─ project/
│   ├─ manage.py
│   ├─ settings.py
│   │  
│   ├─ config/
│   │   ├─ base.py
│   │   ├─ production.py
│   │   └─ ...
│   └─ ...
└─ nginx/
    └─ default.conf
```

this is the error what i got:
[image]

container log:

```
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.26.43.151:8000'. You may need to add '172.26.43.151' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] Traceback (most recent call last):
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] response = get_response(request)
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 135, in __call__
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] response = self.process_request(request)
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] host = request.get_host()
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 152, in get_host
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] raise DisallowedHost(msg)
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.26.43.151:8000'. You may need to add '172.26.43.151' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:13] Bad Request: /
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.26.43.151:8000'. You may need to add '172.26.43.151' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] Traceback (most recent call last):
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 56, in inner
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] response = get_response(request)
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 135, in __call__
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] response = self.process_request(request)
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 48, in process_request
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] host = request.get_host()
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 152, in get_host
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] raise DisallowedHost(msg)
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '172.26.43.151:8000'. You may need to add '172.26.43.151' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
[6/Jul/2023:11:18:14] Bad Request: /
```

Comment: Please add your settings.py. Is your .env formatted like that? That wont work..

Comment: I have added my settings and working directory

Comment: "Tried ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*'], but it didn't work." If the IP address/hostname was the issue, then that should have fixed it. What exactly happened when you tried that?

Comment: @markB
I have provided the error can you check it please.

Comment: That error indicates you did not actual deploy the update with `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']` in your settings. It looks like you are trying to set it via environment variable? What happens if you just hard-code `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']`?

Comment: @MarkB
I have tried multiple methods to resolve the error and hard-code like you say with ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'], but I keep encountering the same issue. Despite attempting different approaches, the error persists.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the settings.py file is being loaded? If you add a `print` to it, does it show up in the container logs?

Comment: @MarkB
yes i am sure because it working when i run it locally, i will try to print out any thing in deployment

Comment: I've tried to print in the local.py it working and print out in local environment when build the image locally, but nothing appears on container logs lightsail when deploy the image only the same error appears

Comment: "yes i am sure because it working when i run it locally" but the default `ALLOWED_HOSTS` allows `localhost` so I'm not sure how testing it locally verifies that the settings file is being loaded.

Comment: So you are printing the settings now, and locally it works, but on AWS those aren't printed out? Then that sounds to me that the settings file isn't being picked up when running in the container, at least when running using the exact settings you have configured in Lightsail. Do you have environment variables set locally that you are missing in Lightsail?

Comment: this is exactly what happens, all environmentints in docker-compose environment but I did not configured any environment on Lightsail as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py` you define ALLOWED_HOSTS as `ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_HOSTS", "").split(",")`, this means that in your `.env` you need to add it as `'host1,host2'` not as a list.

Comment: you are right, i was define allowed_hosts to 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv("ALLOWED_HOSTS", "").split(",")
and ALLOWED_HOSTS='host1,host2'  in .env .
but not it working so i tried to hard coded ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings to
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*'] but it also not working